# Using crontab to delete tmp folder files created by apache user

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions, cron

Currently I have it set up such that users can download zip files from my site, and they're stored in `/tmp/zip_file_dir/`. The PHP script first downloads them from my CDN using `ftp_get()` and then places them in that folder such as `/tmp/zip_file_dir/random_hash_folder/file_here.zip`. Then I simply use `readfile()` to initiate the download for the user. That all works fine.

However, I then later use a cronjob to clear this folder out (the script deletes the downloads after `readfile()`, but if the user cancels the download script the files aren't deleted by it hence the point of the cronjob to clean these up).

The `file_here.zip` file has the permissions `-rw-r--r--` with the owner `apache`. Each `random_hash_folder` in `zip_file_dir` has the permissions `drwxr-xr-x` with the owner `apache`. The cronjob simply scans the zip_file_dir and uses `rmdir()` and `unlink()` to delete the files.

The cronjob is run by a user with sudo access to the server (i.e. more permissions and abilities than the `apache` user). However, I keep getting PHP "Permission denied" notices when trying to delete the files.

I've tried added the sudo user running the cron job to the `apache` and `nobody` groups as mentioned elsewhere in some of my Google research, but that hasn't brought me any luck.

Any ideas how I get this cronjob to delete those files?

Edit: I am using RHEL.

Comment: That the user has sudo privileges does not mean they are necessarily acting with elevated privileges.  Are you actually invoking sudo to perform the operations that require elevated privileges?

Comment: No, I know I'm not using the sudo privileges. I said that more as a way to let you guys know that I do have the ability to get the right privileges somehow but that I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any more permissions and abilities than the Apache user.  Since the apache user created those files, the apache user can destroy them.  The apache user seems like the most appropriate user to me.

You can either put your cron job in the apache user's crontab ( `sudo crontab -u apache -e`) or run the job from root's crontab as the apache user:

```
1 5 * * * su apache -c "/path/to/cleanup_script.php"
```

Choose the option that helps you keep track of your cron jobs the easiest.

Comment: Adding the cronjob under the apache user worked. Which makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can either run cronjob from the Apache web server (so in Cron you put only HTTP call), as well you can make sure that all your permissions on the files and folders are 777 when you are creating them. When making a folder, you can specify mode, and when you creating the file, you can make the same. You can also use setacl on that folder, so both users have permission, and it's propagating down the folder, like this:

```
# mkdir /tmp/zip_files
# chown apache:apache /tmp/zip_files
# chmod og-rwx /tmp/zip_files
# setfacl -m u:test:rwx zip_files/    # allow test user to enter the folder
# setfacl -m d:u:test:rwx zip_files/  # assure test permissions to created files and folders
# setfacl -m u:test:rwx zip_files/
# getfacl /tmp/zip_files
```

Where "test" is your user you run the cron from.

ps. Forget sudo, you dont need to access root to do it.

Comment: I do know the `random_hash_folder` folders are being created with `mkdir($dir, 0777)`. However, when creating the file I simply use `ftp_get()` which has no way of specifying permissions and using `chmod()` right after it in the script doesn't appear to work either. With regards to `setfacl`, my server says "Operation not supported". It's RHEL.